# Proving the following relation

Tags: number-theory

If $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes show that 
$$p^{q-1}+q^{p-1}=1 \bmod pq $$

In this question what I did was I wrote out the Fermat's relation and got

$$p^{q-1}=1 \bmod q$$
$$q^{p-1}=1 \bmod p $$

But now what to do?

Please help.

Comment: Finish with CRT.

Comment: Please elaborate

Comment: Please add a solution

Comment: You probably noticed immediately, but did not mention,  that (for example) from $p^{q-1}\equiv 1\pmod{q}$ it immediately follows that $p^{q-1}+q^{p-1} \equiv 1\pmod{q}$, since the second part is congruent to $0$ modulo $q$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Chinese Remainder Theorem. If it's true mod $p$ and mod $q$, it's true mod $pq$.

Answer (score 0):

${\bf Hint}\,\ {\rm mod}\ p,q\!:\ x\equiv 1\,\Rightarrow\, {\rm mod}\ pq\!:\ x\equiv 1\ $

${\rm because}\ \ \ \ \ p,q\,\mid\, x  - 1\quad\ \Rightarrow\quad\ pq\,\mid\, x - 1,\ $ by $\ p,q\,$ coprime.

Alternatively you can  use CRT (Chinese Remainder Theorem) to make that inference.

Comment: Could you just give illustration how to do so with  CRT

Comment: @user3650050 By CRT the "obvious" solution $\,x\equiv 1\pmod{pq}\,$ is *unique*. CRT is overkill, since lcm suffices. The uniqueness part of CRT is equivalent to $\ a,b\mid c\iff {\rm lcm}(a,b)\mid c.\ $